# Tengo un error al compilar este programa

Tags: base-de-datos, c

Estoy intentando hacer un programa que me permita crear una lista dinámica de piratas por una tarea que me encargó mi universidad, pero no compila. La terminal de Visual Studio Code me dice que es por **tipos de puntero incompatibles**. Aquí está la parte del programa que me da error:

```
pirata_t * crear_pirata(pirata_t *lista, char* nombre, int dinero, bool cerrado){
    pirata_t *nuevo,*aux;
    nuevo=(pirata_t *)malloc(sizeof(pirata_t));
    strcpy(nuevo->nombre,nombre);
    nuevo->cofre=crear_cofre(dinero,cerrado);
    return nuevo;
    nuevo->sgte=NULL;
    if (lista==NULL)
   {
        lista=nuevo;
   }
   else
   {
       aux=lista;
       while(aux->sgte!=NULL)
       {
           aux=aux->sgte;
       }
       aux->sgte=nuevo;
   }
}
```

Me pueden decir qué hice mal y cómo corregirlo? Gracias por adelantado

Comment: Es complicado ayudarte sin ver todo el código o la lista de errores que recibes. Por favor incluye los errores y las estructuras al menos. Por cierto, en C no existe `bool` como tipo fundamental, seguro que no estás usando C++?